# Apply pd.cut across rolling windows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.random_integers(1, high=10, size=50)})
```

I can cut this dataframe into bins of a percentage pieces (1% bins below) between minimum and maximum values and put the intervals and the occurrences:

```
df["bins"] = pd.cut(df['a'], np.arange(df["a"].min(), df["a"].max()*1.01, 1), include_lowest=True)
df["counts"] = df.groupby(df["bins"]).transform("count")
```

What I want to achieve is that I want to apply the same functionality across predefined windows across the dataframe. If the window value is 10, for example, it should create the same 'binds' and 'counts' value for each consecutive 10 periods. I know I could use `df["a"].rolling(10)` yet I couldn't associate this with the `cut` function. Is there any efficient way to do that?

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe with expected output, perhaps with a smaller window size.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [rolling apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=50)})
def f(s):
    d = s.to_frame().groupby(pd.cut(s, np.arange(s.min(), s.max()*1.01, 1), include_lowest=True)).transform("count")
    return d[0].mean()

df["a"].rolling(10).apply(f)
```